# How to check if a Merge query was succesfull in JAVA (ResultSet)?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to check if this query returns a result or an error. 
I use the `next()` method, for **SELECT** querys synce it checks if there's a next row but not sure about **MERGE**

```
public ResultSet example{   
    String sqlQuery = "MERGE INTO bonuses b "
    +"USING ( "
    +"SELECT employee_id, salary, dept_no "
    +"FROM employee@link_to) e "
    +"ON (b.employee_id = e.employee_id) "
    +"WHEN MATCHED THEN "
    +"UPDATE SET b.bonus = e.salary * 0.1 "
    +"WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "
    +"INSERT (b.employee_id, b.bonus) "
    +"VALUES (e.employee_id, e.salary * 0.05) "

    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
      rs = stmt.executeQuery();
      Err.errN(rs);
    } finally {

    }
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: Use `executeUpdate()`. It will return the number of affected rows. `executeQuery()` is **only** for statements returning a result set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
........
int affected_rows_number=stmt.executeUpdate("your_query");
```

`affected_rows_number` show you how many rows affected. You can understand it worked or now.